# Reliable HTML/Ajax control to manipulate tree structures?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree, treecontrol

Can someone recommend a reliable HTML tree control that also supports tree manipulation? 
I need it for a backend and want to move, reorder, delete, add and rename nodes.

Right now I use a nested set model in my database to store the tree structure, and dhtmlxTree (see dhtmlx.com) as tree control. 
The problem I'm having is that this control needs an extra field in the database to store its own addressing schema (something like 0_2_14, that's the path to this item from root). This is a pretty bad idea, because it means whenever the position changes the whole tree becomes invalid (since it uses this string as ID and adress/position at the same time), I have to re-calculate each node, close the tree and reload it from the server. This annoys the users, because they have to reopen the tree each time to the place they where before. The documentation says this tree control can indeed pre-select/open the tree to a given address, however this feature is not working for me - I use ajax calls to poll only the immediate child for a node whenever the user opens a node, and for some reason it wont let me open a node on load in that case. The documentation is crap and it only has very few and basic code examples for some functions, so im stuck here.
My question is if there are any good alternatives out there, that don't have issues with it's own addressing scheme and allow edits. Would also consider a flash or maybe java app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/tree
http://www.jstree.com/

see if the above one is useful.

Comment: Thanks, jstree.com looks awesome. had a look at the jquery plugins before, but the few i had seen didn't support any modifications to the tree.